# Can't use pagination on hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pagination, eloquent

Here's my category model:

```
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
}
```

Then i am printing all products that each category has:

```
@foreach($category->products as $product)
    {{ $product->title }}
@endforeach
```

However it prints every related product to this category. How can i use pagination in that case? I've tried to print pagination links at the bottom:

```
<div class="pager">
    {{ $category->products()->paginate(12)->links() }}
</div>
```

It does print pagination links correctly, but when i change the page - content is not changing.

Answer (score 4):

Before sending data to view first paginate the result like this.

```
$products = $category->products()->paginate(12);
```

now pass this value to the view and just iterate it.

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product->title}}
@endforeach
```

To display links just call links method on the products in the view.

```
{{$products->links()}}
```

Comment: Didn't work. has no effect. Still displays all products without pagination.

Comment: That's weird, please show your code which values are you passing to the view and how and what are you doing in the view. Can you paste your new code?

Answer (score 2):

You want to call paginate your products first:

```
public function products() {
     return $this->hasMany('Product');
}

public function recentProducts() {
     return $this->products()->paginate(12);
}
```

Then in your view you loop through

```
@foreach($category->recentProducts() as $product)
     {{ $product->title }}
@endforeach
```

Then your links

```
<div class="pager">
    {{ $category->recentProducts()->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: You don't use `Paginator` as a relation result.

Comment: The relation is in a separate method. Having another method `recentProducts` means he can reuse the paginated results on other pages

Comment: OK, if you don't use it as a relation, then yes. However what you mean by reusing it on other pages?

Comment: Didn't work. It prints not 12 items per page, it does print all 24 items and pressing pager links has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Pass paginated collection to the view:

```
// controller
$products = $category->products()->paginate(12);

// view
@foreach ($products as $product)

   // do what you need
@endforeach

// links:
$products->links();
```